# php $_SERVER doesn't have HTTPS value

Tags: php, https

Ok, I've got an odd one here: I have an ssl cert set up for a client domain. On that domain I have a php script that does nothing but print_r out the Php $_SERVER super global. In a browser I go to **https**://www.example.com, but not only is there no HTTPS value in the $_SERVER array, the SCRIPT_URI is **http**://www.example.com, SERVER_PORT is 80, SERVER_PROTOCOL is HTTP/1.1.

What could possibly be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bad proxy/load balancer/forwarding type of thing where the actual web server is not receiving the request directly. Any more info on the setup?

Comment: Not really. It's a cheap shared server with network solutions. I am using some basic mod rewrite rules, but otherwise it's just out of the box hosting. Is this something I should be calling network solutions about? When it comes to servers I'm clueless.

Comment: Yes, asking the host how the HTTPS status is communicated by the web server would be a good idea.

Comment: Ha. Yeah, asking the host how the servers are set up does make sense, doesn't it. Thanks. You were right on too. After hours on hold, countless automated menus and more than a few technical support operators, I was finally told exactly what you said I would be. Have to solve the problem on the font-end. See my answer below. Maybe you can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Network Solutions redirects https queries behind a firewall or some such nonsense, so there is no way to detect an ssl connection on the server side.

I've handled the redirect with the following bit of javascript. Not the cleanest solution, but it seems to work.

```
if(window.location.protocol == "http:")
    window.location.href = "https://" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when using a shared hosting service (Perhaps they are using load balancers).  The site in question is a WordPress site and the core WordPress is_ssl() function would fail and not bring up the site because of this.

I found a WordPress specific workaround here:

```
<?php
// based upon https://gist.github.com/webaware/4688802

// if site is set to run on SSL, then force-enable SSL detection!
$siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
$position = stripos($siteurl, 'https://');

if ($position === 0)
{
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

    // add JavaScript detection of page protocol, and pray!
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'force_ssl_url_scheme_script');
}

function force_ssl_url_scheme_script()
{
    ?>
    <script>
    if (document.location.protocol != "https:")
    {
        document.location = document.URL.replace(/^http:/i, "https:");
    }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Install as mu-plugin, such as mu-ssl-fix.php

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is the correct behaviour of PHP. The https stuff is represented as http in the super global `$_SERVER` array. I also had problems with this bizarre behaveour.
I hope that helps you.